# Get radio checked in an array in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, forms, radio-button

I got the next html code and i want to get the array of checked radio buttons:

```
    <tr>
    <td>¿Cómo te llamas?</td>

    <td><input class="radio" type="radio" name="respuesta1" value="female"> Pablo</td>
    <td><input class="radio" type="radio" name="respuesta1" value="female"> Christian</td>
    <td><input class="radio" type="radio" name="respuesta1" value="female"> Alberto</td>


    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>¿Cuánto es 2 + 2?</td>


    <td><input class="radio" type="radio" name="respuesta2" value="female"> 2</td>
    <td><input class="radio" type="radio" name="respuesta2" value="female"> 3</td>
    <td><input class="radio" type="radio" name="respuesta2" value="female"> 4</td>

    </tr>
```

As you can see, there arte two questions but i want only get the checked radios in a jquery array for the correct answers. Can you please help me?

Comment: you want the value of selected radio element?

Comment: Yes, that's what i want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this might work

```
$(".radio:checked").each(function() {
console.log($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this then

```
    var selectedradio = "";
    var selected = $("input[type='radio'][name='respuesta1']:checked");
    if (selected.length > 0) {
        selectedradio = selected.val();

    }
```